# Autowired Repositories With Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to reach my repositories with reflection to reduce readability complexity in the project. I have to cache 3 DB tables with regarding a cacheTable.  These tables are;

I.**TEST_PARAMETERS**

II.**TEST_REAL_TRANSACTION_CRITERIA**

III.**DEV_USER_STDLOV**

If I dont use reflection, I have to use switch case to use repository according to table name such as:

## WITHOUT REFLECTION

```
@Autowired
private TestCacheListRepository testCacheListRepository;

@Autowired
private TestParametersRepository testParametersRepository;

@Autowired
private TestTransactionCriteriaRepository testTransactionCriteriaRepository;

@Autowired
private DevUserStdlovRepository devUserStdlovRepository;

for (TestCacheListEntity entity : testCacheListEntities) {
            String cacheKey = entity.getCacheKey();

            switch (cacheKey.toLowerCase()) {
                case "test_parameters" :
                    cachedObject.put("test_parameters", new ArrayList<>());
                    for (TestParametersEntity testParametersEntity : testParametersRepository.findAll()) {
                        cachedObject.get("test_parameters").add(testParametersEntity);
                    }
                    break;

                case "test_real_transaction_criteria":
                    cachedObject.put("test_real_transaction_criteria", new ArrayList<>());
                    for (TestRealTransactionCriteriaEntity testRealTransactionCriteriaEntity : testRealTransactionCriteriaRepository.findAll()) {
                        cachedObject.get("test_real_transaction_criteria").add(testRealTransactionCriteriaEntity);
                    }
                    break;

                case "devuser_ngi_stdlov":
                    cachedObject.put("devuser_ngi_stdlov", new ArrayList<>());
                    for (DevUserStdlovEntity devUserStdlovEntity : devUserStdlovRepository.findAll()) {
                        cachedObject.get("devuser_ngi_stdlov").add(devUserStdlovEntity);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
```

On the other hand, if I use reflection, I'll get something like this but I am encountering problem with it.

## WITH REFLECTION

```
List<TestCacheListEntity> testCacheListEntities = testCacheListRepository.findAll();

        for (TestCacheListEntity entity : testCacheListEntities) {
            String className = CaseFormat.UPPER_UNDERSCORE.to(CaseFormat.UPPER_CAMEL, entity.getCacheKey()) + "Repository";
            try {
                Class c = Class.forName(className);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

First problem is;

Code jumps into catch block and says

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TestParametersRepository
```

or

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TestRealTransactionCriteriaRepository
```

or

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DevUserNgiStdlovRepository
```

Also I need to use these repositories with @Autowired annotation. Is it possible to use like this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Reflection is the last thing you need here, and it will not improve the readability, but will make things needlessly complex, slow, and hard to understand.

You can avoid repeating the same code thrice, though, by simply using a better OO design. For example, assuming, based on the code you posted, that your 3 entities extend the same base class or implement the same interface BaseEntity:

```
private Map<String, Supplier<Collection<? extends BaseEntity>> suppliersByCacheKey = new HashMap<>();

... 

@PostConstruct
void init() {
    suppliersByCacheKey.put("fraud_parameters", () -> fraudParametersRepository.findAll());
    suppliersByCacheKey.put("fraud_real_transaction_criteria", () -> realTransactionCriteriaRepository.findAll());
    suppliersByCacheKey.put("ndvlive_ngi_stdlov", () -> ndvNgiStdlovRepository.findAll());
}
...

for (FraudCacheListEntity entity : fraudCacheListEntities) {
    String cacheKey = entity.getCacheKey();
    List<BaseEntity> listToCache = 
        new ArrayList<>(suppliersByCachKey.get(cacheKey).get());
    cachedObject.put(cacheKey, listToCache);
}
```

In traditional, business code, reflection is almost always a terrible idea. Learn polymorphism, data structures, design patterns: those are the tools you should use.